# How do I calculate the variation of a function?

Tags: functions, stochastic-calculus, integer-partitions, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to understand how to calculate the variation of a function. In this regard, the book that I am reading offers the following definition -

$$V_g([a,b] = sup \sum_{i=0}^n |f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)|$$

Now, I understand that x represents partitions of the interval in which the function *f* is defined. But, I am confused how can the supremum be taken. I mean, essentially, it will summate the modulus of the difference between two real numbers, which will be a real number, like, say *c*. Why will a supremum be required?

(EDIT: *sup* moved outside the summation based on the helpful responses below!)

Comment: It is the $\sup $ of $\sum_k |f(x_{k+1}) -f(x_k)|$ taken over all partitions of $[a,b]$.

Comment: You seem to have left out the question...

Comment: Yes - This is my first question on Math SE - so, I didn't know there was a word limit. I am rephrasing my question.

Comment: You've got the $\sup$ in the wrong place. It goes outside the summation, as copper.hat said. You consider all possible partitions of $[a,b]$, for each of them the sum is a real number, and you take the supremum of all the sums.

Comment: @Rahul - Thanks! I understand the concept now. Just one quick question - so, the partitions of an interval need not be mutually exhaustive, like the partitions of a set? It's the only way that I can see that a supremum will be required (because it would essentially create a set).

Comment: The partitions divide the interval into subintervals. For example, you can divide $[0,1]$ into $[0,1/2]$ and $(1/2,1]$, or $[0,1/3],(1/3,1/2],(1/2,1]$ or whatever. The definition of the total variation takes the supremum over the results you get for all such partitions.